# python selenium - locating a text on a website, and storing it in a variable

Tags: python, selenium

https://gyazo.com/9f153457558977341c95019206010e00
This is the one text I want to store in a variable from the website.
How do I do that?
This is what I came up with:

```
text = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.vip-additional-text > *:nth-child(1) > p')
print(text)
```

output:

```
[]
```

It returns an empty list for some reason, can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text and not the webElement you should try:

```
text = browser.find_element_by_class_name("vip-additional-text").text
```

Comment: thanks, but what if I only wanted the first. line, the first <p> "some text in here</p>

Comment: No problem ;) yes it can be done... I don't have a working example right now in python, but it's a subject for a different question with more details...

Comment: The code you showed me prints it all out on the side. I only wanted the first line. How do I all the other stuff apart from it?

Comment: You need to parse the text to get what you want, for example if you want only the first line it's something like: `text.splitlines()[0]`